# How to see the code generated by the compiler for OpenMP constructs

Tags: openmp

If I have a program that uses OpenMP, is there a way I can see the transformed code generated by the compiler, that is the code the compiler actually compiles. Actually I'm interested in seeing what code the compiler replaces for OpenMP constructs. I'm using Visual C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say what version of Visual Studio you were using.  For VS 2008 take a look at /FA, /Fa here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6(v=VS.90).aspx.